# Android Studio remember keystore and password

Tags: android-studio, android-keystore

Whenever I build a signed apk this dialog appears:
[image: dialog]

Every time I have to enter the same texts (path, passwords, alias).

My question: how to save and remember them, across projects? Ticking "Remember passwords" does not help.
My keystore file has been generated a while ago and used in Eclipse many times.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file -->project structure-->click on app-->and on the right side 4tabs will appear and select build in that and enter your detail. That's it
Also important are these in your **build.gradle** file

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        ProdSigningKey {
            keyAlias 'any alias name'
            keyPassword 'your actual password'
            storeFile file('keystore file path on your computer')
            storePassword 'your actual password'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but on the "Build types" tab I see no options to enter my key, password etc. Only Proguard file, Application Id suffix, Version Name suffix, Zip align enabled etc.  On the "Signing" tab there are fields to enter password but also "Store File" and I do not want to overwrite my already existing key file.  I want to use it in AS.

Comment: For Android Studio version 3.5.3 the settings are in:

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> App -> Signing Configs. 

After entering the data, you just use Build -> Build APKs, and it will be signed (use "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jarsigner" -verify APKFile.apk to check).  The password prompt still comes up for me.  Can someone verify this? If so I will edit main answer if possible.